# Failed to Convert Date Format to Text Format on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can some one help me?
I've tried convert date format on excel using this formula

```
=TEXT(D1,"yyyy-dd-mmm")
```

but it doesn't work and shows me an error.

I want to format it because date field gave me wrong value when I want send it to database using this formula

```
="INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES ('"&A1&"', '"&D1&"')".
```

[image]

Comment: What are the values of `A1` and `D1` ?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Excel - please correct your tags.

Comment: As per the question guide you post data as formatted text and errors as quoted text.

Comment: And please ensure your comments are professional.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen A1 and D1 values are actually date data as example 7/11/2021 , but it gave me value random number like 41019. So I need to convert it to text 7/11/2021.

Comment: Asking someone "whats wrong with you" is not professional. And I can assure you that this site prefers no images unless the question is a UI or similar question. And please don't call me "bro".

Comment: @PremanTerminal maybe don't be so quick to make assumptions. I did not downvote your question, I gave you some tips for improving your question which you are chosing to ignore.

Comment: @PremanTerminal since you get that error when you enter `=TEXT(D1,"yyyy-dd-mmm")`, it is likely that your regional settings require a `;` rather than a `,`.  Try using `=TEXT(D1;"yyyy-dd-mmm")`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to format the date in a separate cell, you can do it in the one formula.  You also want to use yyyy-mm-dd a the the format for SQL:

```
="INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES ('"&A1&"', '"&TEXT(D12,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"')"
```

Comment: The OP is about getting an error when entering `=TEXT(D1,"yyyy-dd-mmm")`.  Embedding that same formula in another formula won't solve that.